# Some URLs failing to hit application when they are too long

Tags: php, apache

I just recently installed PHP7.1 and run into a few issues with the application at hand. It seems that once the URL exceeds 108 characters the request does not hit the app as if it was not routed correctly.
I take it that there is a php.ini setting that I'm missing which is enabling this behaviour. However I was not able to find anything that worked yet. I saw somewhere else people suggesting to increase or turn off 'output_buffering' in php.ini but that did not work.

Any help much appreciated!

Here's the htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Checking apache error log I get the following error when a request fails in the way I described:

```
[Tue Oct 16 17:05:38.000118 2018] [core:notice] [pid 77] AH00052: child pid 26760 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Tue Oct 16 17:05:38.000542 2018] [core:notice] [pid 77] AH00052: child pid 26759 exit signal Bus error (10)
[Tue Oct 16 17:05:39.074451 2018] [core:notice] [pid 77] AH00052: child pid 26761 exit signal Bus error (10)
[Tue Oct 16 17:05:40.089130 2018] [core:notice] [pid 77] AH00052: child pid 26763 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Tue Oct 16 17:05:40.092705 2018] [core:notice] [pid 77] AH00052: child pid 26762 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Tue Oct 16 17:05:41.195042 2018] [core:notice] [pid 77] AH00052: child pid 26767 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Tue Oct 16 17:05:41.195139 2018] [core:notice] [pid 77] AH00052: child pid 26766 exit signal Bus error (10)
[Tue Oct 16 17:05:41.195381 2018] [core:notice] [pid 77] AH00052: child pid 26765 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Tue Oct 16 17:05:41.195456 2018] [core:notice] [pid 77] AH00052: child pid 26764 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Tue Oct 16 17:05:42.257230 2018] [core:notice] [pid 77] AH00052: child pid 26768 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
```

A working URL would be:

```
http://photospace.local/admin/content/pages?sdkjfhksdjhfjk=sdfkjnasdasdasdsaasdasdsadadfdfafdgfg
```

And a non-working one would be (note this one just has one character more):

```
http://photospace.local/admin/content/pages?sdkjfhksdjhfjk=sdfkjnasdasdasdsaasdasdsadadfdfafdgfaf
```

Comment: share your apache configuration, .htacces and some examples of url working and not working

Comment: This is a standard HTTP limit imposed by Apache. Sending vast amount of data over query string? Consider using POST. Browsers also have such limit built in.

Comment: it's not vast amount of data, it's just a URL with 109 characters or more. So it is way below Apache's limit I suppose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above answer was not the solution, it did fix some scenarios but not all of them. Plenty of URL patterns were failing, or POST requests after submitting a form. I had never encountered this problem before (with the `.htaccess` configuration given above) until I did a clean install of the latest `Mac OSX 10.3.6` and upgraded to `PHP7.2`

After fiddling with .htaccess configurations I found the following which fixed all issues:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

# removes www.
# ------------------------------------------------------------------
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# rewrite "domain.com/foo -> domain.com/foo/"
# ------------------------------------------------------------------
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/|#(.*))$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]

# Yii specific rewrite
# ------------------------------------------------------------------
# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php 

#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me - I'd previously been experiencing many unexplained page failures, with no sign of a solution that I could find, so thank you! I understand the logic of what you're saying above, but I don't understand (a) the cause behind the page failures that this resolves, or (b) how this actually resolves them (even though it clearly does)! Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by removing `LoadModule negotiation_module libexec/apache2/mod_negotiation.so` from Apache's `httpd.conf`

I hope it helps someone else because it is so obscure and just resolved it by chance.

cheers